# How do I chart a new graph for multiple columns where there are 2 series for Y

Tags: r

I have a dataset df1. I would like to chart a line graph with Date as X and Chart1 and T1. I would like to loop it for all column where I would get the same graph when Y is Chart2 and T2 as well as when Y is Chart3 and T3.

```
dput(df1) >
structure(list(Date = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994), Chart1 = c(25, 
34, 19, 7, 4), T1 = c(23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5), Chart2 = c(2, 
4, 12, 9, 15), T2 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10), Chart3 = c(11, 9, 
8, 6, 2), T3 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is the chart that I would like to get for each column (Chart2,T2) and (Chart3,T3) etc.
`ggplot(df1, aes(x=Date)) + geom_line(aes(y=Chart1)) + geom_line(aes(y=T1), color="red")`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may separate out `'Chart'` variables and `'T'` variables and create list of plots.

```
library(ggplot2)

chart_cols <- grep('Chart', names(df1), value = TRUE)
t_cols <- grep('T\\d+', names(df1), value = TRUE)

list_plots <- Map(function(x, y) ggplot(df1, aes(x=Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=.data[[x]])) +  
    geom_line(aes(y=.data[[y]]), color="red"), chart_cols, t_cols)
```

Comment: Hi, I wish to get a new chart for each like (Chart1, T1) (Chart2, T2) etc.

Comment: Ok..so you want to create a different plot for every pair. See my updated answer. You can use `list_plots[[1]]`, `list_plots[[2]]` to get individual plots.

Comment: Can I know what does the .data[[x]] and .data[[y]] do?

Comment: Usually we refer to column names directly in `ggplot` code like `ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) ...` where `x` and `y` are column names. But when we pass column names as string like `"x"` and `"y"` we use the `.data` pronoun to refer to columns.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you.